# Proof of map $\varphi(g\cdot a) = gG_a$ is a bijection

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be an action on $A$, $a \in A$. $O_a$ and $G_a$ are the orbit and stabilizer of $a$.
Let $B$ denote the set of cosets of $G_a$ in $G$.

i) Prove that the map $\varphi: O_a\to B$ defined by
$\varphi(g \cdot a) = gG_a$ is a bijection.

ii) Show that this map is “compatible with the action” in that $\varphi(h\cdot a) = h\cdot \varphi(a)$ for all $h\in G$, $a\in A$.

I know for part i) I have to prove onto and one-to-one, but I am lost after that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For part i) I would remind you that a function is invertible if and only if it's bijective. Can you find such a $\varphi^{-1}$ from it's definition? For part ii) you'll need to show that the coset $\varphi (h \cdot a)$ is the same as the coset $h \cdot \varphi (a)$. Merely expanding what each side of the equation means and using properties of a group action and you'll find this result becomes self-evident quickly.

Answer (score 0):

For **injectivity**: suppose that $\varphi$ maps $\varphi(g_1 \cdot a) = \varphi(g_2 \cdot a)$.  That implies that $g_1 G_a = g_2 G_a$.  Recall that $1$ is the stabilizer of $a$, so $g_1^{-1} g_2$ must stabilize $a$.  But then $g_1^{-1} g_2 a = a$, so $g_1 \cdot a= g_2 \cdot a$.

For **surjectivity** again recall that $1 \in G$ stabilizes $a$.  So $\varphi(g \cdot a) = g G_a \ni g$, which implies that $\varphi(O_a) = \varphi(G \cdot a) = G \ G_a \supset G$.

To show compatibility of $\varphi$, use associativity of the group $G$.

Thus $$\varphi(g \cdot a) = g G_a = g (1 G_a) = g \varphi(1 \cdot a) = g \varphi(a)$$

Now since the stabilizer cosets partition the group $G$, we've just shown the all-important **Orbit Stabilizer** theorem, 
$$|O_a||G_a| = |G|$$